# Initial steps to get up and running with Selenium RC and tests written in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ide, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

Can someone tell me the exact steps (be specific) to test (write tests and then execute them) a website through Firefox using Selenium RC and the Ruby programming language?

I'm new to this and have only done it with Java, Eclipse, and JUnit 4 (and Selenium RC + IDE of course). I'm looking for steps similar to what it took for me to get it up and running with Java.

To get up and running with Java I did the following:

1. Created new Java project in Eclipse.
2. To this projected I added selenium-java-client-driver.jar, selenium-server.jar, and Junit4 Library.
3. Using Selenium IDE I created a test and exported it in the Java language.
4. I created a class in my Java project (in Eclipse) and imported this code; which needed some tweeking.
5. I then click on the "Run " in eclipse and it works great.

Can someone give me comparable steps to get up and running with Ruby and any IDE?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out.

1. Install ruby.
2. Install selenium ide on FF
3. DL and run the selenium server
4. record a test in the selenium IDE
   for FF and export it as a ruby file
5. open command line with ruby
   (confirm by typing "ruby -v") and
   navigate to this newly exported ruby
   file
6. run "gem install selenium-client"
7. "ruby your_file_name.rb". And
   that's it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start from the beginning:

1. Install Ruby - If you're on
   windows, you can go to
   rubyinstaller.org and download an
   installer.. For other OS's, you may
   already have it installed or have
   some form of method to install. I
   don't know those methods,
   unfortunately.
2. Install Selenium.
   If you're starting with a new
   project, use Selenium 2, which is
   still in beta, but which has a new
   interface that avoid some of the
   problems in Selenium 1 (like no
   cross-domain testing). To do this,
   go to a terminal shell or a command
   prompt and type 'gem install
   selenium-webdriver'.
3. Start a
   test - you can record it in IDE and
   convert to Ruby (though that will
   still be Selenium 1's interface) or
   code it directly in a text file or
   an IDE (I use NetBeans Ruby for my
   tests). The basic code you want is:

   require 'selenium-webdriver'

   @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox ' or :ie or :chrome or any of the other browsers
   @driver.navigate.to 'http://www.google.com'

   element = @driver.find_element :name, 'q' 'Not sure of this syntax - I have this wrapped in my code
   element.send_keys "Selenium"

Documentation is here: [API docs](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/index.html#) -  [Notes](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've installed ruby 1.9.2 as well as the gem. I've recorded a test using the IDE in firefox and export it as Ruby(Test::Unit). I have the selenium server running. But now what? How do I actually get the recorded test to run. I assumed that I'd just launch it from the command prompt (with Ruby) and it would start up but doesn't. How do I get the script to actually execute?